# Improving code from several R Markdowns to just 1

Tags: r, function, loops, coding-style, markdown

I am working on a project that requires forecasting on n unique items per location. 
There are 4 locations, so I have created 4 different R markdown files. The only difference in the 4 R markdown files is that the first thing I do is subset the data to 1 of the 4 locations.

Then I render all 4 files to produce my results.

Is there a cleaner way to do all of this instead of in 4 different R Markdown files? Every time I make an adjustment, I have to go back and do it 4 different times instead of just once.

Currently, the R markdown file is set up in the following way:

chunk 1 load the data
chunk 2 subset data to 1 location (lets say USA for example)
chunk 3-60 lots of different lapply, mapply, forecasting, accuracy measurments, etc. 
chunk 61 produce a csv file with results.

Another R Markdown file is exactly the same, except for chunk 2: selecting a different location.

Instead of 4 R markdown files, it would be faster to have 1 R Markdown file.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this example https://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/software/R/markdown_multiple_reports.html

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you are doing something else with the Rmd script than just producing csv files because that's could just be done in an R script, without knitting.

Generally, in an Rmd, I would include in the setup chunk, all libraries, the appropriate read function to bring in the data set, the functions used to process the subsets, and any other constants applicable to the all subsets.

For the output portion, assuming it is identical for all subsets except naming and the specific data, I'd have four chunks that call on the same master workflow function. E.g., assuming a variable "to_subset"

```
my_data %>% dplyr::filter(to_subset == "Class A") %>% master_function()
```

Of course, if there is boilerplate text interleaved with the data manipulation, you'd do this in several chunks with portion_function() in place of master_function.

Depending on the specific output, it can also be helpful to set output variables in the chunk and pull them in through an inline reference.

That's about as specific as I can get without more information concerning the output. As I said, if there is nothing but a csv, you'd be better off just running an R script ending in

```
%>% readr::write_csv(paste("filevar"".csv")
```

and use a purrr:map to apply it to a vector of subsets.